# Spring User authentication Failure not called

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security

I'm having a problem with the Spring User Authentication Failure. Here is my UserAuthenticationFailureHandler class:

```
public class UserAuthenticationFailureHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler{


@Override
public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException{
    ...
    System.out.println("\n test \n");
}
```

and this is the spring-security.xml file:

```
<form-login authentication-success-handler-ref="userAuthenticationSuccessHandler" 
                authentication-failure-handler-ref="userAuthenticationFailureHandler"/>

    ...

<beans:bean id="userAuthenticationSuccessHandler" 
    class="path.UserAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>

<beans:bean id="userAuthenticationFailureHandler"
    class="path.UserAuthenticationFailureHandler/>
```

So the AuthenticationSuccessHandler works perfectly fine and gets called on an successfull authentication. But the FailureHandler just won't get called.

But SuccessHandler looks just like the FailureHandler:

```
public class UserAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
...

@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, 
  Authentication authentication) throws ServletException, IOException {
  ...
    System.out.println("\ntest\n");
}
```

...
}

I'm not sure what I did wrong. Can anybody give me some hints?
Thanks!